# How to read pdf file from document directory with timestamp in iPhone?

Tags: ios, pdf, uiwebview, nsdocumentdirectory

i m having a problem i have too many pdf files so one by one i m downloading pdf files,

so i put timestamp with my document folder so mypath look like this:

```
/Users/zee/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/10EF6B94-0ECD-484A-

AF5A-D300D8EF55DB/Documents/myPDF.pdf1382698338.78128
```

but i dont understand why its not opening in UIWebView with timestamp, my below code is

working when i dont put the timestamp.

so how can i open my pdf file that is attached with the timestamp below is my code please

help me out how to solve this problem

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,

 NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myPDF.pdf"];

    NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];

    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

my filepath is :

```
/Users/zee/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/10EF6B94-0ECD-484A-

AF5A-D300D8EF55DB/Documents/myPDF.pdf1382698338.78128
```

Please tell me how can i open my pdf file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so i put timestamp with my document folder so mypath look like this:
>
> ```
>               /Users/zee/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/10EF6B94-0ECD-484A-AF5A-D300D8EF55DB/Documents/myPDF.pdf1382698338.78128
> ```

You should try using a different scheme for naming you files, so that the extension is kept unmodified, i.e.:

```
  ..../myPDF<TIMESTAMP>.pdf
```

e.g.

```
  ..../myPDF1382698338.78128.pdf
```

Comment: i have done this now my path is something like this ..../myPDF1382698338.78128.pdf
so what should i placed here now ??
 NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myPDF.pdf"];

Comment: you should use: `NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myPDF1382698338.78128.pdf"];`

Comment: can u please look at my another question here is the link: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611517/how-can-i-add-page-curl-effect-in-pdf-file-xcode"

Comment: sergio please do let me know how can i do this, i will be very much thankful to you for this favour