# how can i add page curl effect in pdf file?

Tags: ios, pdf, page-curl

i m getting data from remote server and recieving the couple of pdf file from webservice

i was opening pdf file in my UIWebView, but i want the page curl effect on my pdf file

like normally we have the effect in pageBasedApplication.

i search many tutorials and google it but can't find the simplest solution that how

can i show my pdf file in page curl effect and i can zoom in and out the pdf

Please guide me how can i show my pdf file in page curl effect .

if anyone have the code so please provide me or tell me some simple tutorial that i can

follow, looking forward for you answers.

thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried already? Did you research how the page curl effect is achieved?

Comment: @RyanR i have tried these:
PaperStack,
PageCurlDemo,
leaves,
but i dont understand how to set page curl effect in my pdf file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do that through [`UIPageViewController-PDF`](https://github.com/jackhumphries/UIPageViewController-PDF) (follow full instructions from the github page, though):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myFile" ofType:@"pdf"];
PageViewController *page = [[PageViewController alloc] initWithPDFAtPath:path];
[self presentViewController:page animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

On the other hand, Leaves should also work out of the box; if you get the sample app and replace the PDF file name that should be all.

If you cannot work it out, please, paste your code and explain in detail what does not work for you.

Comment: there's something i want to ask, page curl is working but i can't "zoom in" the pdf document. Thanks

Comment: `UIPageViewController-PDF` does support zooming. Try and set a break point in the `PDFScrollView` delegate methods and see if you get there... possibly you should ask a new question with enough code so that we can know what you are exactly doing.

Comment: would you please check this link i have posted my question here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19829327/uipageviewcontroller-pdf-zooming-not-working-xcode

Comment: :sergio would you please look up my this question i really need your help . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603996/how-to-lock-screen-in-portrait-landscape-in-iphone

Comment: @sergio i done the Page curl by your example it working good in portrait,in Landscape is not showing Full pdf help me

Comment: I assume you have not set constraints or a proper resizing mask. If you need more help, ask a new question and provide all the relevant details.