# UIPageViewController-PDF Zooming not working xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, zooming

I'm using the the below github project

https://github.com/jackhumphries/UIPageViewController-PDF

the problem is pdf is loading and page curl effect is working but i can not zoom in and zoom out my pdf document that is loaded i try debuging as well then why its not working but i can not find out the solution and i checked out the PDFScrollView delegate methods they all are implemented but those methods are not calling when i try to zoom in/out .

here are these methods :

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

       return self.tiledPDFView;
}

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view
{
    // Remove back tiled view.
    [self.oldTiledPDFView removeFromSuperview];

    // Set the current TiledPDFView to be the old view.
    self.oldTiledPDFView = self.tiledPDFView;

    [self addSubview:self.oldTiledPDFView];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale
{
    // Set the new scale factor for the TiledPDFView.
     _PDFScale *= scale;

    // Calculate the new frame for the new TiledPDFView.
    CGRect pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(_PDFPage, kCGPDFMediaBox);

    pageRect.size = CGSizeMake(pageRect.size.width*_PDFScale,  pageRect.size.height*_PDFScale);

    // Create a new TiledPDFView based on new frame and scaling.
    TiledPDFView *tiledPDFView = [[TiledPDFView alloc] initWithFrame:pageRect scale:_PDFScale];

    [tiledPDFView setPage:_PDFPage];

    // Add the new TiledPDFView to the PDFScrollView.
    [self addSubview:tiledPDFView];

     self.tiledPDFView = tiledPDFView;
}
```

And i have this code :

```
-(id)initWithPDFAtPath:(NSString *)path {

  NSURL *pdfUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

  PDFDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)pdfUrl);

  totalPages = (int)CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(PDFDocument);

  self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

  return self;

}
```

and i want to implement this code below to above code

```
/*
 Open the PDF document, extract the first page, and pass the page to the PDF scroll view.
 */
NSURL *pdfURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"TestPage" withExtension:@"pdf"];
CGPDFDocumentRef PDFDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)pdfURL);
CGPDFPageRef PDFPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(PDFDocument, 1);
[(PDFScrollView *)self.view setPDFPage:PDFPage];
CGPDFDocumentRelease(PDFDocument);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this method to PDFScrollView:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
   self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
   if (self) {
     self.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;
     self.delegate = self;

     self.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
     self.maximumZoomScale = 3.0;
   }
   return self;
}
```

and add the last two lines to `scrollViewDidEndZooming`

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale
{
  ....
  self.minimumZoomScale = 1.0/scale;
  self.maximumZoomScale = 3.0*scale;

}
```

Notice that changing page will only work when the page is at its lowest zoom level (as in happens in several reader apps).

Comment: when i zoom in my pdf on max then when i try to zoom out in actuall size so its not zooming out in the actuall size it sometimes stuck on zoom in level and zoom out then not work properly can you please tell me what should i change ???

Comment: have you added the last two lines I mentioned in `scrollViewDidEndZooming`? alternatively, you could just check out my fork of the framework: https://github.com/sdesimone/UIPageViewController-PDF

Comment: yes offcoursee i added the last two lines in scrollViewDidEndZooming. and i also checked out the project you mentioned above, you can also see in there, zoom out is not working correctly, zooming in is working correctly but zooming out having a problem when i try to zoom out it couldn't response perfectly it doesn't come in its actuall position, zooming out having a problem please guide me sergio where i m doing mistake thank you.

Comment: i pulled out the latest version but zooming out is not working when i zoom in on maximum then it doesn't zoom out .

Comment: would you please look up my this question i really need your help . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603996/how-to-lock-screen-in-portrait-landscape-in-iphone

Comment: I'm confused as to why paging should only work when at lowest zoom level, the PhotoScroller demo code from Apple doesn't require this - images can be pages between regardless of zoom level.  Why is this different ???

Comment: @deepwinter: what is "this"? if I understand what you are trying to say: this question/answer does not solve the problem of paging at any zoom level. you should add some logic in order to accomplish that. look into PhotoScroller's code to find out how you can do that.

Comment: Yeah it's a different question, just thought you might have insight.  Photoscroller's code does nothing different that I can see, yet has the functionality I describe.  I've posted a different question to discuss there.