# How to lock screen in portrait/landscape in iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation, lockscreen, landscape-portrait

My Application supports all orientation but in few cases i want to lock the screen in

portrait/landscape mode.

In my Application i have two kind of pdf document.

one is in portrait document and other is landscape document .

i want to open portrait document in portrait view only, and landscape document in

landscape view only.

i want to do like this: if my application is open in landscape view and i click on the

portrait document so it must rotate in portrait view and same like this for landscape if

my application is open in portrait view and when i click on the landscape document it

must be rotate or it must open the document in landscape only.

hope i make you guys clear pardon my english hope you understand what i want please

need your help .

Thank you in advance

here is my some code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

  if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == 
         UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {

            NSLog(@"Portrait");
            if ([orientationObject isEqualToString:@"p"]) {
               //If the document is portrait
                pdfScrollViewFrame = CGRectMake(-0.0, -80.0, 770.0, 1085.0);
            }
            else{
                // If the document is landscape
                pdfScrollViewFrame = CGRectMake(-0.0, -40.0, 770.0, 1130.0);
            }
        }
        else{

           NSLog(@"Landscape");

            if ([orientationObject isEqualToString:@"p"]) {
             //If the document is portrait
               pdfScrollViewFrame = CGRectMake(65.0, -80.0, 620.0, 1110.0);
            }
            else{
                //if the document is landscape
                pdfScrollViewFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, -40.0, 740.0, 1070.0);
            }
        }
```

Comment: this might help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15110838/xcode-how-do-i-keep-views-locked-into-portrait-mode-but-still-allow-one-view

Comment: What does this have to do with `xcode`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For iOS6+, you could add this to your controller:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

  if (<PDF is portrait>)
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
  if (<PDF is landscape>)
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;

  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;

}
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

I am not sure if you need to manually rotate the PDF to get the results you want. In this case you might try with something like:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toOrientation
                            duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    if (toOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape)
        pdfScrollViewFrame.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);

    … // handle all other cases here
}
```

In order to only lock rotation after `viewDidAppear`, I would do following:

```
@interface…
…
   @property (nonatomic) BOOL isRotationLocked;
…
@end

@implementation…
…
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  …
  self.isRotationLocked = YES;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

  if (self.isRotationLocked) {
    if (<PDF is portrait>)
      return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    if (<PDF is landscape>)
      return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
  }
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;

}
…
```

Comment: and i'm using your lastest github UIPageViewController-PDF project in my application, in your project i'm trying to handle the orientation from so many days and as you know i'm keep asking you again and again please help me out.

Comment: actually what i want is, suppose my application is open in landscape view(mode), and when i click to open my portrait Pdf document so the next view(2nd screen) it must rotate the screen in portrait mode. my application supported all orientation but here in opening the document i want to check if the document is portrait so controller should rotate in portrait or if i click on my landscape document and my applicaiton is running in portrait so it should change the orientation in landscape hope you understand what i'm trying to say :(

Comment: Actually that is what I understood. Have you tried my code? If so, could you check whether your app enters the `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and what it does there?

Comment: yes i tried your code and in landscape mode opening my portrait document so it comes in supportedInterfaceOrientations method , and  if (<PDF is portrait>)
      return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait; it comes here as well but doesn't rotate the screen in portrait.

Comment: have you removed setting `pdfScrollViewFrame` in `viewDidLoad`? that should be not necessary anymore… other than that would you check if your `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` if called and with which arguments? what happens if you use the implementation for `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` I have just provided?

Comment: i was doing some mistake somewhere thats why the code was not working, but your code is perfect and its working fine thanks alot :)