# How to open locally saved PDF file in an Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, local-storage

I'm trying to save PDF file to local storage.

I save the file this way and it seems to me that everything is fine.

```
//Get path directory
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

//Create PDF_Documents directory
documentsDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"PDF_Documents"];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];

filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory, tastingName];

[tastingNotesData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

This way I try to get the file

`tastingPath = /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4255D8B0-33F5-47AA-ABFA-CCC3691DA033/Documents/PDF_Documents/39e0afcdb56240c2a65ab9e136377b32.pdf;`

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[self.productModel.tastingPath lastPathComponent]];

NSData *data2 = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:path];

NSLog(@"tasting notes %@", data2);
```

At the end file will be displayed in the UIWebView.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12707096/how-to-read-pdf-file-from-document-directory-in-iphone) might help

Comment: Why do you properly append a path using `stringByAppendingPathComponent` in one place, but then append more to the path using `stringWithFormat`? Do not use `stringWithFormat` to build a path.

Comment: Hooda PDF is saved from API. URL to saved file You have several lines higher, starting with tastingPath

Comment: rmaddy I found this solution in another topic, some people wrote that it works perfectly and that's why I used it

Comment: @kajz3reczka Just because it happens to work doesn't make it the correct solution. Use `stringByAppendingPathComponent` to build up a path, not `stringWithFormat`. Besides, why be inconsistent and use two different ways to append to a path? Use one (proper) way and be consistent. It makes your code easier to read and maintain and leads to less bugs.

Comment: @rmaddy I will correct the code as you advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is simple. In your attempt to read the PDF file, you don't include the `PDF_Documents` part of the path. Or you are not appending the filename. Can't be 100% sure which part is wrong. It depends on what the value of `[self.productModel.tastingPath lastPathComponent]` is.

Comment: tastingPath contains the PDF_Document part. [Self.productModel.tastingPath lastPathComponent] is exactly 39e0afcdb56240c2a65ab9e136377b32.pdf

Comment: But don't you see the problem? You only access `lastPathComponent` of `tastingPath`. So you are ignoring the `PDF_Document` part of the path.

Comment: holy moly! You have right. Thank you very much :) Now everything work.

Comment: Glad to help. Please don't forget to accept answers that solve your issue. It lets people know you question has been answered.